# PHP: include with separate global scope

Tags: php, scope, global

I would like to merge two php projects. Both projects use global variables so I would like to have separate global scopes.

Example:

file project1.php:

```
$var1 = 'var1';

function print1() {
  global $var1;
  echo $var1;
}

print1();
```

file project2.php:

```
function load1() {
  include('project1.php');
}

$var2 = 'var2';

function print2() {
  global $var2;
  echo $var2;
}

print2();
load1();
```

This would execute project2 just as expected but project1 would fail because $var1 is not in global scope but in the scope of load1().

One possible fix would be to call `global $var1` in load1() but that would mix the two global scopes (messy) and would be complex since the reallive project2 has many global variables and I would have to check if there are any new ones with each update.

So it would be best if I could create a seperate global scope for project1. Is that possible?

Comment: Now, you know why **not to use globals!!** Prepare for spaghetti.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: God no. The actual solution to your problem here is to stop using global variables, and worry only about your top scope, not whether that is the global scope.

Comment: You could also try out namespaces for the different files…

Comment: Sorry, but I failed to understand why do you wrap `include` construct into another function. You know the name of the file you need to include, right? You may need to use some function to prepare the full name of the file included - but not to wrap `include`.

Comment: Please take into consideration to research how to write PHP in these days. Working with such an outdated stype reminds me of PHP3. You should get rid of globals and refactor that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have separate GLOBAL contexts. The sole purpose of the global of the global context is to be "global" whatever happens.

In order to fix this, you should "contextualize" your code refactoring global variables to function arguments :

```
function print2() {
  global $var2;
  echo $var2;
}
```

Becomes :

```
function print2($var2) {
  echo $var2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to wrap your include in a function, take a look at [PHP Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

project2.php:

```
namespace project2 {
    $var2 = 'var2';

    function print2() {
        global $var2;
        echo $var2;
    }

    print2();
}

namespace project1 {
    function load1() {
        global $var1;
        include('project1.php');
    }
    load1();
}
```

Comment: No, it's also valid in PHP >= 5.3.0.